# Python Shodan API - Can't search with filters

Tags: python, api, shodan

When I try to use the Shodan API in Python to search for certain filters, I only get errors. When I search for words as an Example, I do not get these errors. My Python Code:

```
import sys
import shodan

SHODAN_API_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
try:
    api = shodan.Shodan(SHODAN_API_KEY)
    results = api.search("port:21")
    print results["total"]
    for result in results["matches"]:
        print result["ip_str"]+"\n"
except Exception as e:
    print("Code: {c}, Message: {m}".format(c=type(e).__name__, m = str(e)))
```

So were is the actual error? I have a free Shodan account and when I search for "port:21" on the Website I get results. When I do it in the script, I get an error.

Also I'd like to know if it is possible to go through the whole database and getting more than 100 results. I thought about using CIDR (e.g. 1.1.1.1/27)to only search a special range under 100 and do it over and over again. But is this even possible? Or are there more efficient ways doing it?

Comment: *When I do it in the script, I get an error.*. You catch all errors and replace them with `print "error"`. Remove it and see what the actual error message is.

Comment: "APIError" "Please upgrade your API plan to use filters or paging" OK. The thing is that I have a free account. But why does this not work? On the website it works like a charm. Or does the API requieres a paid account? Anyway: If the API does not work I'll use web-scraping. Or is there another possibility? Because it seem very stupid to me if the developers create an API which is only usable when you have a paid account. I mean, you can easily write your own PHP script or something like that.

Comment: If you want to spend hours of your time writing a scraper and hoping it won't get banned all to save $60, you can definitely do that. I don't think this question is really answerable at this point if the problem is with the API.

Comment: OK, still thanks for your attempt to help me! And yes I'm a student and do not have the money atm. But I'll see the scraper as a way to test my scripting abilities.

Comment: They may have a free student account plan (or they did at some point), it probably won't hurt to ask if your project is academic.